# Kotlin-parcelize plugin and synthetic binding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin-android-extensions, android-viewbinding

We are a company with 10+ apps all using 10+ internal SDKs, all coded back at the glorious time of the `kotlin-android-extensions` gradle plugin. We heavily rely on both `@Parcelize` and synthetic binding (all our views are coded with it). With the newer versions of Kotlin, this plugin is now deprecated in favor of `kotlin-parcelize` for `@Parcelize` and [View Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) as a replacement for synthetic binding.

We tried to upgrade our Kotlin version from `1.4.10` to `1.6.0` while still using the `kotlin-android-extensions` plugin. We suddenly had a `@Parcelize` error reported [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-42652), fixed in Kotlin `1.5.0`. Except that the fix is not in Kotlin itself, it is in the `kotlin-parcelize` plugin. And of course as they deprecated `kotlin-android-extensions`, the later doesn't contain the fix. So in short, in order to fix the issue we have to use `kotlin-parcelize`.

Knowing that `kotlin-parcelize` can't be used along `kotlin-android-extensions` (build error), and that switching all our views from synthetic to view binding will be a hell of a work that will take a tremendous amount of time, what can be done here ? We really want to keep using synthetic binding while being able to upgrade Kotlin to its latest versions.

Comment: How many classes are affected? As [this comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-42652#focus=Comments-27-4691649.0-0) notes, you might just implement `Parcelable` manually on those, if there are not too many.

Comment: I'd say we currently have around 50-60 classes annotated with `@Parcelize`, so whether we choose to not use `@Parcelize` or synthetic binding, it will be some work... And I really enjoy the simplicity of `@Parcelize`, I don't feel like not using it to be honest.

Comment: "I'd say we currently have around 50-60 classes annotated with `@Parcelize`" -- but, how many give you the error? My interpretation of that bug report is that it is tied to generics.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't understand at first. I remember of 7-8 classes with generics that gave the error. We didn't try to compile all our SDKs but I think the number should be around 10. So yes indeed it is a nice workaround solution that will not cost much time. Maybe I'll give it a try no one has a better answer. Do you know of any good website or plugin for generating a `Parcelable` implementation ? I see that there is an Android Studio plugin that looks nice.

Comment: I think there used to be one at parcelable.com, but it appears to be gone. There is http://parceler.org/ if you want an independent library, though it seems like it will generate Java.

Comment: Alright I'll see what's available. Thanks for your help CommonsWare

Answer (score 1):

What looks like the obvious choice is that you need to move from synthetic views as soon as possible although it might not be possible due to lack of resources.

### Old-school approach

A solution to get around the Parcelable problem is to figure out the classes that are not properly parcelized and serialize them in an old-school fashion.

### Serializing to JSON

I suggest you take a look at the `kotlinx-serialization` package it's quite handy to read from and write to JSON.

For those that don't work you can provide the following parcelable implementation which would be generic and work all around the codebase:

1. Ensure that your classes are annotated with `@Serializable` **important** that such annotation comes from `kotlinx.serialization` package and not the java one.

With this generic function you can write any `@Serializable` object into a parcel.

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T> writeToParcel(out: Parcel, data: T) {
   val jsonString = Json.encodeToString(data)
   out.writeInt(jsonString.length)
   out.writeByteArray(jsonString.toByteArray())
}
```

And with this other one you should be able to deserialize such object

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T> readFromParcel(input: Parcel): T {
  val size = input.readInt()
  val bytes = ByteArray(size) { input.readByte() }
  val jsonString = bytes.toString()
  return Json.decodeFromString<T>(jsonString)
}
```

You can make them extension function from `Parcel` to write even less code.

This should get you around the classes that are problematic for the `Parcelize` extension; it's not as fast as a proper Parcelable implementation but hey, it works.

#### Side notes

Note that the code has written directly as an answer of this post and hence untested and some parts might need adaptation. And of course, check out the [`kotlinx.serialization` documentation](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/basic-serialization.md#basic-serialization) to see how to create the `Json` encoder and decoder (it's fairly simple)